# is it possible in Pimcore to create version for Child when parent object changes it's inherited Fields/Properties/Objectbricks?

Tags: inheritance, pimcore

In Pimcore, I have a parent object with children, and each child inherited some fields from the parent.
I want to create a version for a child if the parent changes its property that child inherited.
If parent changes and nothing changed in child, I don't want to create any version. Just for inherited fields.
In addition, object has object bricks. It is also possible to update the values in there.